# 3 divs horizontally, set last's height to auto

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs, each with `width:100%`, placed under each other.
Here's how it looks:

[image]

My code is:

```
<div class="welcome">
   <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</small>
</div>
<div class="welcome2">
   <h1>About</h1>
   <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<small>
</div>
<div class="welcome3">
   <h1>Why choose us?</h1>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 why">
         <i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-3x why-icon"></i>
         <strong>Fast support</strong>
         <p>Our moderators will help you with your problem.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 why">
         <i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-3x why-icon"></i>
         <strong>Fast support</strong>
         <p>Our moderators will help you with your problem.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 why">
         <i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-3x why-icon"></i>
         <strong>Fast support</strong>
         <p>Our moderators will help you with your problem.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 why">
         <i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-3x why-icon"></i>
         <strong>Fast support</strong>
         <p>Our moderators will help you with your problem.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 why">
         <i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-3x why-icon"></i>
         <strong>Fast support</strong>
         <p>Our moderators will help you with your problem.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 why">
         <i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-3x why-icon"></i>
         <strong>Fast support</strong>
         <p>Our moderators will help you with your problem.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.welcome
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3BA666;
    background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #4DAC71 50%, #3BA666 50%);
    padding: 50px;
}

.welcome2
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FF61E7;
    background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #FF61E7 50%, #FF61D0 50%);
    padding: 50px;
}

.welcome3
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #32C8DE;
    background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #32D0DE 50%, #32C8DE 50%);
    padding: 50px;
}

.why
{
    /** text-align: left; **/
    padding: 15px;
}

.why-icon
{
    color: #0E495C;
    display: block;
}
```

I want it to be like that - first two are normal height, and the last one always fill the empty white space. Is this possible?

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/21dydo07/1/

Comment: Set height % for each div. Like 25, 25, 50%

Comment: Do you want to have fix height for all 3 divs?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. Anything not changes at all.

Comment: I want fix height for only last div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with CSS3. 
Give the design's parents (body, html, ...) a height of 100%. Then set some height to .welcome and .welcome2, e.g. 200px each. After that, set .welcome3 to take the rest, like this:

```
html, body {height: 100%}
.welcome, .welcome2 {height: 200px}
.welcome3 {height: calc(100% - 400px)}
```

Another solution would be to set specific height for every element (that would also be CSS2 comapatible), but that wouldn't allow you to always fill 100% of the screen height and have the third div with a variable height.

If you need the first solution, but you also need CSS2 compliance (e.g. for IE8), then you might need a javascript fallback, that will set the height to .welcome3 accordingly at pageload, something like this (needs jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".welcome3").css("height",$(window).height()-400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the sentences in the first two blocks can be wrapped to single-line, use this:** 
You could use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
Make sure that the wrapper for these three has a `height` style.
For `.welcome` and `.welcome2`, set `padding` and `line-height` either in `px` or in `em`. For example, if the calculated height comes out to be `300px` use `height: calc(100% - 300px)` for `.welcome3`. Note: The spaces around the operator `-` are important.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **Flexbox**,  set `min-height: 100vh;` on `wrap` div and `flex: 1;` on `welcome3` so it will always take free space of viewport

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.welcome {
  background: #3CA666;
  padding: 20px;
}

.welcome2 {
  background: #FF61D0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.welcome3 {
  background: #32C9DE;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="welcome">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome2">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</small>small>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome3">
        <h1>Welcome 3</h1>
        <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</small>
    </div>
</div>
```